# Undefined reference to CreateProcessWithLogonW

Tags: c, winapi, mingw

So I've been working on a small app that at some runs runs an application as another user, I'm writing it in C and using the MinGW GCC compiler to compile and link it. My issue is that whenever I try to use the WINAPI function CreateProcessWithLogonW() I get an error that says "Undefined reference to CreateProcessWithLogonW()."

This is in spite of the fact that I link the Advapi32 when I compile it like so,

```
gcc file.c -lAdvApi32 -o filename
```

Comment: Just a wild guess. Try putting `-lAdvApi32 ` at the end of the command. SOmething like, `gcc -o filename file.c -lAdvApi32 `

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but this doesn't seem to change how it compiles, still getting the error.

Comment: @Betlander I'd recommend using the `-Wall` compiler flag, as this will warn about implicit declarations, which - as it turns out - was the real problem you were having.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct solution is to actually #include the correct mingw32 headers: i.e.

```
#include <windows.h>
```

Though the solution that Anthales proposed works, it doesn't scale well.

Comment: Ah, so it was really just an incompatible implicit declaration and NOT a linker problem; I only thought about the last.

Answer (score 0):

Try linking with the dll in question directly, like so:

> gcc file.c %windir%\system32\advapi32.dll -o filename

When you use the switch -lAdvApi32 instead, you will link with libadvapi32.a from MinGW/lib. Sadly, I can't answer why this won't work; maybe this lib is outdated, or has a completely different meaning